# Craft 3 Upload To Bluehost - Index.php outside root issue

Tags: craft3, server

I'm having issues uploading my craft3 site to Bluehost.

I've uploaded all the files, ran composer install and it does actually work. However when I go to my domain it shows the raw files/folders and I have to go in to my 'public_html' folder to access the site.

I must note I changed the 'web' folder to 'public_html'.

Because the index.php file is inside the public_html folder my server can't find an index file and therefore shows the raw files.

That's my understanding.

What's the best approach for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without getting too much into it, i feel you need to look at a symbolic link for public_html to the web folder (if you have linux server):

https://www.shellhacks.com/symlink-create-symbolic-link-linux/

Or change .htaccess file:

https://www.expression-web-tutorials.com/bluehost-main-domain-sub-folder.html